# How to exclude self-traffic in Google Analytics on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, google-analytics

I'm using Google Analytics iOS SDK to traffic app events and pageviews. It works great.

When I code/debug the app, I don't want Google Analytics to traffic my events or pageviews, cause they're useless. So, is there a way to exclude self-traffics on iPhone with Google Analytics iOS SDK?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I do for Google Analytics is have seperate account ID's for live apps and for debugging.

I store the account ID to be used in the app inside a plist. So when the time comes to debug the app I change the account ID from the live ID to the debugging ID.

Comment: EASY is BEST! Thank you Siddharth Iyer.

Answer (score 2):

You could put an #ifndef around the code that starts tracking. Define a custom User-defined build setting for your Debug configuration called `__DEBUG__` then use it in your code like this:

```
#ifndef __DEBUG__

//code to start analytics tracking

#endif
```

This will prevent your debug builds from tracking but your release/distribution builds will track properly.